# Global search field searching through multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a MySQL Table that holds vehicle information with the following columns:

```
year (int)
model_name (varchar)
chassis (int)
engine (int)
body_type (text)
```

I have a search box that I want the user to be able to search for a particular model and then show the results via AJAX. Everything is working as expected, with one hitch: it only shows results that match a single column.

For example, lets say I have the following row in the table:

```
year: 1965
model_name: Mercedes 220SEb
chassis: 111.014
engine: 127.982
body_type: Sedan
```

Right now, I Can get this to show up by searching either for `1965` OR `Mercedes 220SEb`, but it doesn't show up by searching for `1965 Mercedes 220SEb`, which is what I would like.

Here is the query (passed via AJAX / $.post as $_POST['search'])

```
$like_search = '"%' . $_POST['search'] . '%"';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ac_models WHERE year LIKE ' . $like_search . ' OR model_name LIKE ' . $like_search . ' OR chassis LIKE ' . $like_search . ' OR engine LIKE ' . $like_search . ' OR body_type LIKE ' . $like_search . ' ORDER BY year ASC';
```

How can I modify my query to match multiple columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want. I explode the search string by every space and search every column for every part. Each word has to be in any column.

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
if (preg_match('/[;"\']/', $search)) {
    die('Possible SQL Injection');
}
// maybe strip . and , from numbers here
$sql_where = '';
foreach (explode(' ', $search) as $searchpart) {
    $like_search = '%' . $searchpart . '%';
    $sql_where .= ' AND (' .
        'year LIKE ' . $like_search .
        ' OR model_name LIKE ' . $like_search .
        ' OR chassis LIKE ' . $like_search .
        ' OR engine LIKE ' . $like_search .
        ' OR body_type LIKE ' . $like_search . 
        ')';
}
if ($sql_where == '') {
    die('no search criteria given');
    // to return everything: $sql_where = ' AND 1=1';
}
$sql_where = substr($sql_where, 5);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ac_models WHERE ' . $sql_where . ' ORDER BY year ASC';
```

Comment: Whats the purpose of the `$sql_where = substr($sql_where, 5)` statement?

Comment: Nevermind, just realized it was to remove the first ` AND (` from the string.

Comment: This was perfect, did exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have set up your fields. `LIKE` works only on strings/characters so you will have to `CAST` them before use. At the moment your code will only work for `model_name` and `body_type`. The other `int` fields will be compared as a whole (just a hint: in your example you have set chassis to be '111.014'. This is not possible for an integer field...)
E.g.

```
 ... WHERE CAST(chassis as CHAR) LIKE '%111%'
```

Please be aware that this is **VERY** slow.